# erlang otp download

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

what is the different download from http://code.google.com/p/otp-base/ and  http://www.erlware.org/?

Comment: Please stop tagging all your erlang posts with 'earlang'.

Comment: sorry, actually i didnt know how to spell it  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://code.google.com/p/otp-base/ they say:

> Our source is kept in our GIT powered
>   repo's. See erlware.org for more
>   detail or just fetch it with
>   git clone http://git.erlware.org/otp-base.git